# Convert an Excel file from .xlsm to .xlsx

Tags: excel, vba

I found VBA code to convert an Excel file from .xlsm to .xlsx.

As far as I understand, the code creates a copy of the worksheet which is then converted into .xlsx. This creates two files within a folder, and promptly deletes the .xlsm file.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FullPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    MsgBox "YOU WILL GET A WARNING AFTER COMPLETED, PLEASE WAIT"

    ThisWorkbook.Save

    On Error GoTo XETA

    FullPath = "File path" & ".xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FullPath

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FullPath)
    wb.SaveAs Left(FullPath, Len(FullPath) - 1) & "x", 51
    wb.Close False
    Kill FullPath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "COMPLETED CORRECTLY"
    Exit Sub
    XETA: Debug.Print
End Sub
```

The script tends to work around half of the time. It fails by not deleting the .xlsm file used to create the .xlsx file. The purpose of the conversion is to utilize the file in a power automate flow, therefore I need to convert the .xlsm to a .xlsx file.

Comment: Try replacing `Debug.Print` after the label `XETA:` with 
`Msgbox Err.Description` - at least then you will get a clue about the error message

Comment: The error message says "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

Comment: Don't you open files from older Excel with extension `.xls`?

Comment: Does `Set wb = Nothing` before `Kill` solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Export `ThisWorkbook` Without Macros

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ThisWorkbook.Save ' ?
    ExportThisWorkbookWithoutMacros "C:\Test\Test"
End Sub
```

- The following sub is written as a function to return the (full) path of the newly created workbook.
- This might become useful if e.g. you don't want to show the message box but you want to test if the creation was successful and retrieve the file path, e.g.:

  ```
  Dim FilePath As String:
  FilePath = ExportThisWorkbookWithoutMacros("C:\Test\Test", False)
  If Len(FilePath) = 0 Then 
      MsgBox "The file could not be created!"
  Else
      MsgBox "Created """ & FilePath & """!"
  End If
  ```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

- Copies all sheets of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`) to a new workbook and saves it to the given location as a macro-free workbook (`.xlsx`).
- When you don't supply the file extension and the file format, the file is attempted to be saved as a macro-free workbook which the newly created workbook actually is 'regarded as' since it has not been saved yet.
- `PathBaseName` is the file path without the file extension.

```vb
Function ExportThisWorkbookWithoutMacros( _
    ByVal PathBaseName As String, _
    Optional ByVal ShowMessage As Boolean = True) _
As String
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export 'ThisWorkbook' Without Macros"
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    swb.Sheets.Copy
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation...
        dwb.SaveAs PathBaseName
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' ... and don't ask about the macros
    
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dwb.FullName
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Success = True

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        If Success Then
            ExportThisWorkbookWithoutMacros = dFilePath
            If ShowMessage Then
                MsgBox "Exported 'ThisWorkbook' to """ & dFilePath & """!", _
                    vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
        Else
            If Not Application.DisplayAlerts Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

From the [XlFileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) enumeration:

> xlWK3 15  Lotus 1-2-3 format  *.wk3

Why you're saving as Lotus format, while you're want the macro save as macro-free workbook?

You need to change the code to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FullPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    MsgBox "YOU WILL GET A WARNING AFTER COMPLETED, PLEASE WAIT"

    ThisWorkbook.Save

    On Error GoTo XETA

    FullPath = "File path" & ".xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FullPath

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FullPath)
    wb.SaveAs Left(FullPath, Len(FullPath) - 1) & "x", 51 '
    wb.Close False
    Kill FullPath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "COMPLETED CORRECTLY"
    Exit Sub
    XETA: Debug.Print
End Sub
```

Comment: Am I blind or is the only thing you've changed to the code the `XETA:` part? Also, OP has used 51, not 15 for the xlFileFormat

Comment: Why you're saving as Lotus format, while you're changing ".xlsm" to ".xlsx" only?